# How can I change the style of thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file-upload

I am completely unexperienced with Javascript and jQuery.
I want to have a fileupload with jQuery using the Fileupload plugin.
It works almost fine but I also want to have a preview of every uploaded picture, so I decided to create thumbnails of uploaded pictures next to the progressbar of the file. To do that I want to change the style by using css. But how can I link the thumbnail to my css file?
That is the code which creates the thumbnail and there I need a relation to my css file.

```
add: function (e, data) {
            $('body).append('<img src="' + URL.createObjectURL(data.files[0]) + '"img width="220px" height="120px"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css"/>');
```

Unfortunately the  tag does not work.

Comment: Just add the style sheet to your page. When using the proper names, your javascript generated content will take over this style.

Comment: But how can I add the stylesheet to my page? Sorry, I am really new in Javascript. Can you maybe tell me, how I have to change my code?

Comment: Just add the link tag to the head of your html page. (Maybe you can post the contents of your stylesheet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the image with correct classes that already exists in your .css file it should automatically apply the correspondent styles.

Also, don't forget to correctly close the body selector

```js
add: function (e, data) {
            $('body').append('<img src="' + URL.createObjectURL(data.files[0]) + '" width="220px" height="120px"/>');
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: First of all thanks for your replies. The css part is called #thumbnails and is located in /assets/styles.css. Styles.css is included and works for all other uses. But I don´t know, how to call the #thumbnails in this case.

Comment: Can you add the #thumbnails css in your question?

Comment: you have to add the `id` attribute to your `img` tag when you append it to the `body`. Anyway IDs are for single use, if you want to apply the same rules on multiple images then you should use a class.

Answer (score 2):

1) You cannot append a CSS file after page load. So remove the tag from the append function.

2) Add your CSS file in the `head` tag beforehand.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <!-- head content -->
    <link href="/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

3) Create a new classname in your CSS file containing the styles you want your thumbnails to have

CSS:

```
.myThumbnailStyle{
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    etc...
}
```

4) Add that classname to your thumbnail `img` tag

```
$('body).append('<img class='myThumbnailStyle' src="' + URL.createObjectURL(data.files[0]) + '" width="220px" height="120px"/>');
```